# submenu is showing partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to develop *one submenu* under "**Share registry operations**" named as "Insider...". But I am getting only partial submenu getting displayed.
URL: http://sampledemos.online/gnsa/

I tried with the below CSS codings.

```
.menulist ul ul li a {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #90d4e9;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -23px;
}
```

I'm trying to create a submenu named "Insider..." under "share registry operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below to your CSS. Your javascript sets a bad clip path, probably due to negative margins. You might want to look closer into that aswell.

```
#listMenu-id-2 {
  clip: inherit!important;
}
```

Comment: clip: rect(0px, 437px, 154px, 0px) !important; - this gives exactly what I need, Thanks for your ideas @Trickytree22

Answer (score 2):

Try this code..

**css**

```
.menulist ul ul {
 left: 227px;
 clip: inherit !important;
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes tried but cant see the submenu named "Insider.."

Comment: It is working,when I keep the cursor at the menu end but not on the menu middle position, any other suggestions,

Comment: For this, need to change all the menu style.. because you are used custom menu for dropdown.. it will take time to fix this.. please use someother menus..